# What is the best way I can take my book from iBooks and converted into a EPUB format

Tags: books

I would also like the ability to show my book through Kindle without having to start over with an EPUB format iBooks has a scroll widget that will make it difficult to convert I believe looking for  any help

Comment: For Kindle I think you need mobi format instead of epub

Comment: If the book has Drm then there is nothing that will allow this.

Comment: Right now it's unclear where you are coming from (in which format the book you want to convert is), and where you are heading to (EPUB is something different than Kindle). Also the remark about the scroll widget seems to be a bit strange here. Can you please edit your question to be more specific about what you want to accomplish here?

Comment: Have you tried searching for online converters?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use Calibre:

> calibre is a powerful and easy to use e-book manager. Users say it’s
>   outstanding and a must-have. It’ll allow you to do nearly everything
>   and it takes things a step beyond normal e-book software. It’s also
>   completely free and open source and great for both casual users and
>   computer experts.

https://calibre-ebook.com/about

There is a conversion discussion [here](https://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=290871).

You can also try exporting your .ibooks format to .pdf, and using Calibre to convert that to the format you need.  How well these conversions will work you can only tell by testing it.

Comment: I don't think calibre can read ibooks format.

Comment: I used to use Calibre a lot and in my memories yes it can. Perhaps by adding some extensions. Btw, downvote for an "I think", is a little bit rude..